# Getting acces to maps place favorites

Tags: c#, location, windows-phone-8.1, cortana

In WP8.1 the MS maps app has favorite places like Home and Work. Cortana uses them of course. Is there a public API to get access to those information and even set new places?

Answer (score 0):

Not at the moment. The only thing you can "ask" Cortana right now is to fire up your app with the argument you told her.

There's no way to get to her notebook, that's where all that info is stored.

Not sure if I'd want third party apps getting into that info. That's what Cortana uses to give you accurate answers, if third party apps can 'get in there' it could trick her into giving you "wrong" info/answers/directions.

Comment: Ok, but at least the calendar app and Microsoft maps app uses the same places. So I thought there yould something. A task like in new Appointment would be nice to set a new place.

Comment: I agree, it would be great to have some APIs to 'talk' to Cortana :)

Comment: For any who are interested in upvoting I've posted a feature request: Windows-Feedback:?contextid=383&feedbackid=6b72a2e1-cf5e-45f8-bf84-85aea5c570ec&‌​form=1&src=2