# Can you programmatically access Cortana's favorite places on a Windows Phone?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, bing-maps, cortana

On Windows Phones, you can set favorite places in Cortana like 'Home' and 'Work'. Is it possible to programmatically access these locations to drive location aware scenarios in an app?

Answer (score 0):

No there's no way to do this. Feel free to vote for the request :-) https://windowsphone.uservoice.com/forums/101801-feature-suggestions/suggestions/7577067-allow-programmatic-access-to-cortana-s-places-rem

This is possibly a duplicate of: 
[Getting acces to maps place favorites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27436694/getting-acces-to-maps-place-favorites)

Comment: Now posted as Windows 10 dev feedback: Windows-Feedback:?contextid=383&feedbackid=6b72a2e1-cf5e-45f8-bf84-85aea5c570ec&form=1&src=2